# Highcharts - Pie chart with parial doughnut overlap

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to get such a result in Highcharts:

[image]

Labeling positions don't matter, just partial doughnut overlapping two slices of the inner pie.

I am trying to adopt this example without success: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut

Is there a way to do it in Highcharts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two basic `pie` series and cover one of the points by setting the same `point.color` as background color:

```
series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3],
    size: '60%'
}, {
    data: [{
        y: 1,
        color: 'white'
    }, 5],
    size: '80%',
    innerSize: '60%',
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0mvtf7pe/

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data.color

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Some tweaking was required to display labels properly: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukasn/sqdvwh79/3/)

Comment: Hi @lukaszn, This example can be also useful for you: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cag643n5/

Comment: Disabling data labels is straightforward. How to disable tooltip for the invisible part of doughnut ? I tried something like: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukasn/5cznyL9r/1/) but this disables tooltip for visible part of outter doughnut as well, which should not be the case.

Comment: @lukaszn, I think in this case it will be better to use `ignoreHiddenPoint` property for series and disable `visible` option for a the point: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z2e9u7r6/

Comment: that works well. Here's my complete solution with tooltips and data labels [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukasn/5cznyL9r/4/)

Comment: one last more please before we close this topic. On drilldown (actually drillup) the hidden slice appears back: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukasn/4uc7v9sn/2/). I've tried to fix it on chart events but no luck.

Comment: @lukaszn, The problem is caused by animation. You can use async function: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3wy5ab0c/, or disable the animation: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p6a0rwbo/

Comment: Animation causes flickering on drillup. I suppose we cannot do any better.